# About rational points and the Zariski tangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that this question has been asked here at least twice, but all versions of it don't seem to clarify the specific part I'm confused at. To make things worse, Ueno's book seems to bypass this making me think I'm stuck at something trivial. So here it goes

Given a $k[t]/{<t^2>}$ - valued point $Φ$ on $X$, I'm having trouble understanding why the $x$ corresponding to the image of $<tmod(t^2)>$ is $k$-rational. $k$ is a field

Again I'm terribly sorry if this is trivial or has been asked before and I missed it.

Comment: Because the corresponding point is given by $\mathrm{Spec} k \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec} k[t]/(t^2) \rightarrow X$?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see it

Comment: How do you define a $k$-rational point? Here's one definition: $x\in X$ is $k-$rational if the residue field $k(x)$ is contained in $k$. If I use this definition, then from the fact that I have a map $\mathrm{Spec} k \rightarrow X$ mapping the underlying closed point to $x$ implies that I have a field extension $k(x) \hookrightarrow k$.

Comment: Yes, you 're right. Thank you very much. It's over 4 am here. Thanks to you now I can go to sleep. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $k-$rational point of $X$ is given by a map $\mathrm{Spec} k \rightarrow X$, and we say that the image of the closed point $x$ is $k-$rational. In this case we have a map $\mathrm{Spec} k \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Spec} k[t]/(t^2) \rightarrow X$, where the first map is the inclusion of the closed point of $\mathrm{Spec} k[t]/(t^2)$. So we see that the image is $k-$rational.

Comment: Hey loch, sorry to bother you again. I found a second definition of $k$-rational points that says that the residue field must coincide with $k$. How can I show it using this definition?

Comment: @Amontillado Ah so I realised that I should have said that $X$ is defined over $k$ and that the map $\mathrm{Spec} k \rightarrow X$ is a morphism of $k$-schemes.  Now if we have a $k$-rational point given by $\mathrm{Spec} k \rightarrow X$, then we have an extension of fields $k(x) \hookrightarrow k$. But by assumption $k(x)$ is a $k-$algebra and the inclusion $k(x) \hookrightarrow k$ is the identity on $k$, hence we must have $k(x) = k$. This is found in Liu's algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves Example 3.29.